# Auto Mapper C# .. Add data to mapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper, dto

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeSkill, EmployeeSkillDTO>(); 
 });

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

List<EmployeeSkill> ski = context.EmployeeSkill.Where(r => !r.IsDeleted && r.EmployeeID == employeeID).ToList();
List<EmployeeSkillDTO> mapObj = mapper.Map<List<EmployeeSkill>, List<EmployeeSkillDTO>>(ski);

return mapObj;
```

it return

```
[
   {
    "SkillID": 1,
    "EmployeeID": 83,
    "YearOfExperience": 8,
    "Major": "major",
    "SkillName": null,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "CreatedBY": 29,
    "CreationTime": "2018-05-14T15:53:06.203",
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdateTime": null
},
```

I need to return SkillName from Skills table ... I tried by :

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeSkill, EmployeeSkillDTO>().ForMember(x => x.SkillName, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Skill.SkillName)) 
 });
```

but it doesn't work .. Any suggestions

Comment: Have you tried .MapFrom instead of .ResolveUsing?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with the mapping? Have you checked if `ski` contains your Skill items?

Comment: @dlxeon yes i tried it but not working

Comment: @oerkelens yes i tried it without mapping and have skill name by skillName = r.Skill.SkillName

Answer (score 0):

You need to do either one of two things

1. Stop using `.ToList()` on your query result and use `ProjectTo()` plus `opt.Map` instead of 'opt.ResolveUsing` in your config.  (preferred).
2. Call `Include` when you retrieve EmployeeSkill and Include the SkillName table.  (This will get extra data you don't need).

**Method #1:**

```
var ski = context.EmployeeSkill.Where(r => !r.IsDeleted && r.EmployeeID == employeeID);
var mapObj = ski.ProjectTo<EmployeeSkillDTO>();
```

**Method #1 Config**

```
cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeSkill, EmployeeSkillDTO>()
   .ForMember(x => x.SkillName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Skill.SkillName));
```

**Method #2:**

```
var ski = context.EmployeeSkill.Include(x => x.Skill)
    .Where(r => !r.IsDeleted && r.EmployeeID == employeeID).ToList();
```

Comment: First i can't find .Map , Do u mean MapFrom ? .. Second I get error IMapper doesn't contain definition for projectTo.

Comment: I think its an extension on `IQueryable`. You should be able to call it on `ski` and not on `mapper`

Comment: To compliment @DanielLerps comment here is the link to the documentation for [AutoMapper's IQueryable](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) extension. That's where Daniel Gimenez is getting the `ProjectTo()` and `Map()` calls from